# How do I SSH into multiple switches using a file containing dictionaries for each switch?

Tags: python

Here is the 'myswitches' file, containing the list of IP addresses of different Switches:

```
192.168.122.15
192.168.122.16
192.168.122.17
```

I have managed to successfully telnet into multiple switches using the 'myswitches' file:

```
import getpass
import telnetlib

host = "localhost"
user = input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

f = open('myswitches', 'r')

for IP in f:
    IP=IP.strip()
    print("configuring switch " + (IP))
    host = IP
    telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    telnet.read_until(b"Username: ")
    telnet.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    if password:
       telnet.read_until(b"Password: ")
       telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

    telnet.write(b"config t\n")
    telnet.write(b"int loop 10\n")
    telnet.write(b"ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255\n")
    telnet.write(b"end\n")
    telnet.write(b"exit\n")

    print(telnet.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

**Now I want to use Netmiko to SSH into the switches using the 'myswitches' file:**

Here is the 'myswitches' file again, this time I've used dictionaries instead of a list:

```
iosv_l2_S1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.15',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco',
}

iosv_l2_S2 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.16',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco',
}

iosv_l2_S3 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.17',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco',
}
```

Here is my Netmiko python script that I am currently working on:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

f = open('myswitches', 'r')

myswitches = [iosv_l2_S1, iosv_l2_S2, iosv_l2_S3]

for switches in f:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**switches)
    for n in range (2,11):
        print ("Creating VLAN " + str(n))
        config_commands = ['vlan ' + str(n), 'name Python_VLAN_' + str(n)]
        output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
        print (output)
```

How do I improve my netmiko python script and I also want it to configure `loopback0 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255`.

Comment: if you keep it as Python's dictionary then you should `import`, not read it. But you would have to change extension to `myswitches.py`  and use `import myswitches` and later `myswitches.iosv_l2_S3['ip']`. If you don't want to import then better keep it in different format - ie. `csv` - or create one dictionary then you would read it as `JSON` file. But in `JSON` you would have to use `"` instead `'` and you can't use `,` after last element in dictionary or list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as was responded to in the comments--convert my_switches to my_switches.py and then import it.

```
from my_switches import iosv_l2_S1, iosv_l2_S2, iosv_l2_S3

config_list = []
for n in range (2, 11):
    print ("Creating VLAN " + str(n))
    new_vlan = f"vlan {n}"
    config_list.append(new_vlan)
    vlan_name = f"name Python_VLAN_{n}"
    config_list.append(vlan_name)


for switch in [iosv_l2_S1, iosv_l2_S2, iosv_l2_S3]
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**switch)

    output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_list)
    print(output)
    net_connect.disconnect()
```

So should be something like the above. It will be better if you send all the config commands at once instead of one at a time separately (to avoid Netmiko entering/exiting config mode each time which is slow).

Also as mentioned above--you could use JSON or YAML if you really wanted to read them in as a non-Python file.